# Potential and factorial limit that tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial, indeterminate-forms

I've a question about this limit. As you can see it has a potential argument and a factorial one as well.

> $$\frac{n^p}{n!} $$
>   ($p$ belongs to $N_1$)

When the limit tends to infinity, the fraction stays like this $\frac{\inf}{\inf}$

But because the factorial is bigger than the $n^p$, the limit tends to zero.
My question is: how can I prove mathematically that the factorial term is bigger than the potential one?

Thank you so much for your help. If something is not very clear, please let me know.

Comment: [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation): $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_n:=\frac{n^p}{n!}$, then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=(1+\frac{1}{n})^p \frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$. Hence the series $\sum_{n \ge 1}a_n$ is convergent. Therefore $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: (+1) because this proof does not need the stirling-approximation.

Comment: We have $(1+\frac{1}{n})^p$ and not $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ !

Comment: @Arthur Since $p$ is fixed, we do not even need this comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on JMoravitz's comment, take the natural log to get $\ln(n^p/n!)$. Simplifying, we get $\ln(n^p) - \ln(n!) = p \ln n - \ln n!$, then we use the [approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $\ln n! \approx n \ln n - n + o(\ln n)$ to get $(p-n) \ln n - n$.

Now find the roots of $(p-n) \ln n - n$. Will this approximation have a root?